# Mod of a Mod, solving $x\equiv 2 \pmod{3\pmod{4}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm interested in solving equations like this.
$$x\equiv 2 \pmod{(3\pmod{4})}$$

This means that

$$x-2\equiv 0 \pmod{(3\pmod{4})}$$

$$x-2\equiv 0 \pmod{(4k+3)},k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

which seems to indicate then that

$$x-2=(4k+3)m; $$
for $k,m\in\mathbb{Z}$

So if we distribute out we can say then that

$$x-2-3m \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$$

Then

$$x\equiv (2+3m) \pmod{4}$$

which then

$$x\equiv (2\pmod{3})\pmod{4}$$

However, this doesn't seem to be correct.  I think my issue is at the top in replacing 3 mod 4 with 4k+3.

Comment: What does the notation $x\equiv 2\pmod{3\pmod 4}$ even mean? It doesn't look standard at all.

Comment: So if $\exists k,m\in\Bbb Z\colon x-a=(bk+c)m$ is your **definition** of $x\equiv a\pmod{(c\pmod b)}$, what is your actual question?

Comment: I'm interested in solving x is equivalent to 2 (mod (3 mod 4)).  It seems that it is equivalent to (2 mod 3) (mod 4).  That is my question.

Comment: Since $3\bmod 4=3$, does this mean something different than equivalence modulo $3$? And I have equally no idea what "(2 mod 3) (mod 4)" would mean.

Comment: So maybe my notation is off.  So if I have integers and I look at the equivalence class of 2 mod 3, i would have $x=\{...,-4,-1,2,5,8,...\}$.  then modding out by 4 would return that $x=\{...,0,3,2,1,0,...\}$.  So it seems that this wouldn't have any specific solutions, and I suppose is nonsensical.  I might have to go back and reformulate what i'm asking.

Comment: You might consider writing the problem as two simultaneous equations: $x \equiv 2 \pmod n$ and $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Comment: If $(4k+3)\mid(x-2) $ for all $k\in\Bbb Z $, then $x=2$.